# Trying to send a response from express to jquery-iframe-transport

Tags: jquery, node.js, iframe, formidable, jquery-iframe-transport

I'm trying to set up a simple file upload using jquery-ifram-transport and nodejs the problem is i keep getting the error caught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin `"https://localhost:8081"` from accessing a frame with origin "serverURL". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Here is my clients ajax code from the client

```
var uploadXhr = $.ajax($scope.nodeSocketUrl + '/upload?tenant=qa',{
                    data: $(':text', form).serializeArray(),
                    files: $('#presentationFileUpload'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    iframe: true,
                    processData: false,
                    context: this
                });
```

Here im just having a hard time getting this plugin to work with formidable I would like for a request to be sent back to the client like hey file has been uploaded something like this.

```
form.on('end',function(){
res.header({'content-type': 'text/html'});
        res.send('<html><textarea data-type="application/json">{"ok": true, "message": "Thanks so much"}</textarea></html>');
});
```

Anyone who knows how to sent back a request from express to a jquery-iframe-transport ajax request would be a huge help here.

Update Here are my current cors settings

```
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Express?

Try this:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
 });
```

You need to enable CORS headers for it to work properly.

http://enable-cors.org/index.html

Edit:

Sometimes you need to configure your browser. Localhost behaves differently than actual domains.

Start Chrome with these settings: `--disable-web-security`

Read more about it here:

- [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy)
- http://joshuamcginnis.com/2011/02/28/how-to-disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/

Comment: added my cors in the comments

Comment: Ya went to the command line and entered start chrome --disable-web-security same error occurs